# SML Basis Library: what's the rationale for `ArraySlice.copyVec`?

Tags: sml, ml

### Prior understanding

According to [The ArraySlice structure](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/array-slice.html) as reported by *standardml.org* (I don't have an SML 97 manual to check, only an SML 90 PDF manual), `ArraySlice.copyVec` gets an `Array.array` parameter as the destination, and not an `ArraySlice.slice` as one (or at least me) would intuitively expects. Of course, one can use `ArraySlice.base` to get an array and an index for respectively the `dst` and `di` parameters to `copyVec`. Surprisingly, `copyVec` from `ArraySlice`, does not even have a single parameter of type `ArraySlice.slice`. Fortunately, its `src` parameter is of type `VectorSlice.slice`, as intuitively expected.

### The question

What's the rationale for `ArraySlice.copyVec`? Why doesn't it get an `ArraySlice.slice` as `dst`?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, because that would require the additional constraint that both slices have the same length (or at least `dst` is larger than `src`). The current API gets by without such an extra side condition. Also, it would probably be somewhat more cumbersome to use.